# How to detect if the uploaded file is not an image?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

How to check if the file uploaded file is **solely** an image and not video file and anything?

I tested out a simple code that will check if the uploaded file is an image.

**form**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test">
</form>
```

Although I have `accept="image/*"`, I can easily change it to `All types` and get a non-image file.

**code to check if the file is a valid image** (This is only for testing)

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    if(mime_content_type($tmp_file)) {
        var_dump(mime_content_type($tmp_file));
    } else {
        echo 'error1';
    }
    if(getimagesize($tmp_file)) {
        var_dump(getimagesize($tmp_file));
    } else {
        echo 'error2';
    }
}
```

As of now I have 3 test to this, 2 passed 1 failed:

1. Testing an image = passed.
2. Testing a non-image valid **.srt** file = passed (gives an error to `getimagesize`)
3. Testing a valid video file **.mp4** = failed (after the submission, it is loading for 5-10 seconds and not gives any error)

What do I need to do about this? I do not know what is the problem because it does not gives any results from both `var_dump()` and `echo 'errors'`. What I do think now is that **PHP** is accepting the file.

**Note**

I need to do this so that only a valid image will be uploaded.

**Note 2**

The accepted answer on the marked question is not working with me.

**Update**

If I try to upload a video that is less than **128M** it returns something. But if it is greater than **128M** it gets nothing in my `localhost`, but I tested this in a production site it gives me a `REQUEST TIME OUT`.

Comment: image file has limited extension like .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif etc you can check for them

Comment: it's not safe to rely on the extension that a user has given.

Answer (score 1):

Find file extension like this and check for valid types...

```
function  getextension($name){
    $count=substr_count($name,".");
    if($count>1){//some cases have two dotes
        $name= preg_replace('/\.(?=.*\.)/', '_', $name);
    }
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
    return $ext;
}

$name = $_FILES['imageupload']['name'];//Name of the File
$image_extension = getextension($name);

 $allowed_extension = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "jpeg","JPG","PNG","GIF","BMP","JPEG");
 $image_extension=getextension($name);
  if (!in_array($image_extension, $allowed_extension)) {
    $error_flag = 1;
    $message = "Invalid File Format";
 }
```

Comment: I searched and read about not to trust the file extension given by the user.

Answer (score 1):

*Parsing and checking extensions are not enough as per the question points to.*

I suggest to check file **EXIF (Exchangeable image information)** data after loading a file.

You can put basic validation on basis on extension and after that if it succeed , check exif data of image.

For that you will need a separate DLL to load, that will have exif related function.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exif.php

Comment: you mean I get the extension a user given to the file?

Comment: i couldn't understand your point, my mean is check EXIF detail for those where  your test case fails.